# Exact match, or do partial match if no exact match, in a single query?

Tags: mysql

I need to search a MySQL database under the following conditions:

1) If any exact match is found for the keyword, return the number of rows and the results with an exact match.

2) If no exact matches are found, return the number of rows and results with a partial match.

For example, if the keyword was `cake`, and the table had the following rows, the search should return only rows 1 and 5.

```
1| cake
2| pancake
3| cupcake
4| fruitcake
5| cake
6| pie
```

However, if only the following rows were present, the search should return only rows 2-4.

```
2| pancake
3| cupcake
4| fruitcake
6| pie
```

It is trivial to do this in two queries, such as:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS fields FROM table WHERE word = `cake`

//PHP checks for number of rows, if 0, do second query

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS fields FROM table WHERE word LIKE '%cake%'
```

Question: To cut down on trips to the database, **Is there any way to do this in a single query?**

The best solution I can come up with is to match both via OR, using ORDER BY to favor the exact match. However, to cut off the partial matches if an exact match is found requires iterating through the results, which is infeasible if the exact match returns 2,000 results and the partial match returns 5,000 more but I only want to show the first 25 while still showing the 2,000 count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT 3:

The [following](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac5f1/65) does work:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(COUNT(exact.Id), 0), COUNT(partial.Id))
FROM
    Test AS partial
LEFT JOIN
    Test AS exact ON exact.Id = partial.Id AND exact.Name = 'pi'
WHERE
    partial.Name LIKE '%pi%'
```

I deleted my last text here because it was wrong.

EDIT 4:

The following is written in TSQL (I dont know the correct MySql syntax) and return the actual rows  (you can wrap it in a StoredProcedure on your MySql server):

```
CREATE TABLE #Result (Id int, Name nvarchar(max));

INSERT INTO #Result
SELECT * FROM #YourCakeTable WHERE Name = 'cake'

if(FOUND_ROWS() = 0)
    INSERT INTO #Result
    SELECT * FROM #YourCakeTable WHERE Name like '%cake%'

SELECT * FROM #Result
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it's not working as intended. I modified your fiddle to match my silly cake scenario in the question. This correctly returns 1 and 5: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac5f1/1
But this returns nothing (should return 2-4) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cf40/1

Comment: Just realized the example used `=` instead of `LIKE` for the partial match. With that correction, the second fiddle correctly returns 2-4 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cf40/2), however the first fiddle also returns 2-4, instead of 1 and 5 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac5f1/2)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I appreciate your efforts. I'm getting closer, the counts are correct, but what I really want is the actual rows 2-4 or 1 and 5 with the id and name fields in the result, hoping I can then also put SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS at the beginning to get the 3 or 2 cnt from the same query. I'm playing with this to see if I can get it to do that, however I realize it may not be possible without a query so complex it'd be quicker to just do two queries..

Comment: I dont know MySql well (I normally use TSQL) but maybe you can use something like a function you can design in your MySql database. In that you could create a temp table. I think the query would be much more readable and so easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I'n not sure about MYSQL sintax but you can do this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Exact.Apparence IS NULL THEN Partial.Apparence ELSE Exact.Apparence END) as Apparence FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(word) as Apparence FROM Table WHERE word='cake') as Exact INNER JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(word) as Apparence FROM Table WHERE word like '%cake%') as Partial ON 1=1
```

Let me know if it helps you

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait for other answers but seems like joins and cases may be the best road to explore... may make my unsimplified scenario messier than I would like, but that's part of the tradeoffs of life :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT word, count(*) as ExactMatches, 
if(count = 0, (SELECT count(*) from table WHERE word LIKE '%word%' order by word), NULL) as PartialMatches
FROM  table 
order by word
```

What I think would happen here is you would get your

```
word|count exacts|count partials|

cake|100| null
cake|0| 50
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if this is ALL you need for this, but I think it would work, unfortunately it is rather limited with the order by clause...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Exact.Apparence IS NULL THEN Partial.Apparence ELSE Exact.Apparence END) as Apparence FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(word) as Apparence FROM Table WHERE word='cake') as Exact INNER JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(word) as Apparence FROM Table WHERE word like '%cake%') as Partial ON 1=1
```